# list parent/child

Tags: jquery, list, parent-child

I am a jQuery novice. I enjoy using jQuery and am attempting to get better at it.

I have the following list as a menu:

Page home: no child

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>Team 1 Photos</li>
<li>Team 2 Photos</li>
<li>Group Activities</li>
</ul>
```

Sub-page has child

```
<ul class="menu">
<li>Team 1 Photos</li>
<li>Team 2 Photos</li>
<li>Group Activities
    <ul class="children">
    <li>Team 1 News</li>
    <li>Team 2 News</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS is:

```
ul.children {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}
ul.children li{
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 3px;
}
ul.children li:last-child{
    border-bottom:1px solid #999 !important;
}
ul.menu {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
}
ul.menu li{
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 3px;
}
ul.menu li:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

I am trying to achieve; the last `<li>` to have border-bottom if there is no child.
the last `<li>` to have no border if there is a child

I hope I am making sense

I have tried way to either directly apply the border yes/no or add a class so I can apply the style:

```
jQuery('#menu ul li:has(ul)').parent('li').prev()).css('border','1px solid #000');
```

---

```
if (jQuery('.menu li:has(ul)') ) {
  ('ul.menu li:last-child').add Class('borderme');
```

---

```
jQuery('.menu li:has(ul)').append('borderyes');
```

---

An now I am stuck so please steer me in the right direction so I can learn how to achieve this.

Thank you

LRL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your css.

```
ul.menu, ul.children {
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
ul.menu li{
        border-bottom:1px solid #999;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
```

You don't need seperate styles for `.children` because the descendent selector on `.menu` will take care of all the `<li>` in your markup. All `<li>` within `.menu` will now have a border. To remove border from the last child `<li>` of `.menu` if it has a sub-menu, you could use the following code.

```
$('ul.menu > li:last-child').has('ul').css('border-bottom','none');
```

Please note that I have used a child selector in jquery instead of a descendent selector.

Answer (score 0):

here you have one solution:

```
ul.children {
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    ul.children li{
        border-bottom:1px solid #999;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
       padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    /* Remove this css rule
    ul.children li:last-child{
        border-bottom:1px solid #999 !important;
    }
    */
    ul.menu {
        width: auto;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    ul.menu li{
        border-bottom:1px solid #999;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
       padding-bottom: 3px;
    }
    /* Remove this css rule
    ul.menu li:last-child{
        border-bottom:none;
    }*/
```

And, have the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul.menu li:last-child:has(ul)").css("border-bottom", "none");
});
```

We are removing the border only if the `li` has a child.

Hope this helps. Cheers
Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more testing based on the help from Edgar and Amrit I settled on this

```
jQuery('.menu li').has('ul').css({'border' : 'none','margin-bottom' : '0'});
```

Edgar I could not get your solution to work, probably something I did.
Amit strangly when I first tested your solution it worked however, when I changed the page names it stopped functioning.

I appreciate the time you have given in helping me find a solution

Cheers
LRL